# how to add message in contact us page to inbox?

Tags: asp.net

In every website there is "contact us"

which contains "name ,message,mobno,mailid are may be mandatory and submit(button) "

how to do this in html?

When I click submit buton,is it possible to get message added to gmail inbox automatically????

Answer (score 0):

You need to Code for send Mail to your account in the submit button event like below

```
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
// Sender e-mail address.
Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);
// Recipient e-mail address.
Msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
Msg.Body = txtBody.Text;
// your remote SMTP server IP.
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;// only for gmail account
smtp.Credentials=new System.Net.NetworkCredential("AdminEmail@admin.com","AdminPassword");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(Msg);
```

Also you need a Gmail account (user name and password) to send mail

If you are using any other smtp server then `smtp.Port = 25;`  the port number will change

refer this [link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/how-to-send-mail-using-gmail.html)

Comment: Thnku yur code worked...In case entered password is wrong,need error..whats the condition.?

Comment: Only gmail users can use dis types of account.. without having any account,is it not possible to send message to gmail inbox?? (users dont need to have any account.......but msg should go to gmail inbox)

Comment: above code is demo of how an email is send in asp.net, with out an email account you can't send any email.if you want to trace the error  you can put the send function in try catch

Comment: IN every website have u seen "contact us" page where people can enter name/message alone & submit...In this message will forwarded to mail only right..i need this exact where it doesnt ask email accounts

Comment: that message is forwarding to a site admin's email address right? so use that email address

Comment: @ nikhilsreeni : But should not ask from email id...message will go to "To" email.. "From" email id not neccessary.. Or atleast even if ask email id ,should not require password

Comment: you just hardcode or place the admin email address in app.config answer edited

Comment: Ok..Admin id in app.config..Then what code i should follow instead of mentioning gmail id/password in smtphost???? plz refer this http://www.linklaters.com/ContactUs/Pages/Index.aspx (where they never asked of password for that email..)i expect the same

Comment: you don't need to ask email id and password of the website user, you just send mail using your email address and password ,that username and password you have to hard code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Here is the example

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:email@serviceprovide.com" >
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Ur code opening outlook where i should type message... I dont want by opening  outlook..How to do without opening outlook

Answer (score 0):

There are many way in which you can send email, you can do it in [C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371417/Send-Mail-Contact-Form-using-ASP-NET-and-Csharp),[javascript](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-email-form.phtml),any of the [email form generator](https://www.google.com/search?q=email%20form%20designer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#q=email%20form%20html%20code%20generator&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial).

You can decide which one to use based on what you actually need and is best satisfied by which method.